# Jupyter notebook does not reflect library version change in virtualenvironment

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am new to jupyter notebooks and virtualenvironment. I think that I am incurring in a really trivial problem.

I am trying to import matplotlib in a Jupyter notebook and the import works fine. However, it uses the wrong version of the library (installed also systemwide) and I don't know how to force it to use the one in the virtualenvironment.

In my virtualenvironment I want to use a most recent version of matplotlib and therefore I did
`pip install --upgrade matplotlib` in my virtualenvironment. The upgrade worked fine. 
Now if I do `pip show matplotlib` in my virtualenvironment I get:

```
Name: matplotlib
Version: 2.2.5
...
```

Instead, if I do the same command in my home, I get:

```
Name: matplotlib
Version: 1.5.1
```

However, if in my jupyter notebook I do

```
import matplotlib
print ("matplotlib version:",matplotlib.__version__)
```

I get:

```
('matplotlib version:', '1.5.1')
```

Could you please help me understanding what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. First of all, I read [this long post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) that I suggest to everyone using `conda` or `pip`.

Then I understood that *the shell environment is determined when the Jupyter notebook is launched, while the Python executable is determined by the kernel, and the two do not necessarily match.*

I understood this by putting at the beginning of my jupyter notebook the following:

```
paths = !type -a python
for path in set(paths):
    path = path.split()[-1]
    print(path)
    !{path} -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
    print()

!type python

import sys
sys.executable

!pip show matplotlib
```

It showed me that I was still using an older version of the `matplotlib` library.

Therefore I added

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Restarted my jupyter kernel and this solved my problem.

I hope this solution will help someone else in the same situation.